# is Google Cloud Platform capable of providing these things?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a system made up of the following that I'd like to host on Google Cloud Platform:

- web service (apache cxf)
- web server (apache tomcat)
- database (mysql)
- hosted web pages

I'd like to be able to install/set up Tomcat and MySql myself.  I do not want to use someone's canned, prepackaged components.

If this has built in tools to allow load testing that would be a great nice to have but its not required.

What is required is that it essentially runs itself and requires little hands on intervention from me on a day to day basis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the GCP can do all of that.
Just set up a virtual machine inside the compute engine and it will be very easy to maintain and even scale your applications.
My company is doing just that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Google Compute Engine , it's Infrastructure as a Service just like Amazon EC2 or other servers.

Refer https://cloud.google.com/compute/